# Lambert conformal conic projection not working in R using mapproj?

Tags: r, maps, map-projections

This should be an easy one.

```
library(maps)
map("world", projection = "mercator", wrap = TRUE)
map("world", projection = "cylequalarea", param = 45, wrap = TRUE)
map("world", projection = "albers", parameters = c(lat0 = 0, lat1 = 0), wrap = TRUE)
map("world", projection = "lambert", parameters = c(lat0 = 0, lat1 = 0), wrap = TRUE)
```

The first three projections work, but the last one doesn't -- it just shows the Mercator projection. What am I doing wrong?

I know I can use `spTransform` to actually do the projection, but I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: What were you expecting the LCC projection to look like at lat0 = 0, and lat1 = 0?

Comment: @MikeJewski something different than Mercator? I'm trying to make a comparison like this: (https://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/media/upload/tutorials/qgis-basics/albers.jpg)

Comment: I'm not extremely well versed in GIS stuff, but to my knowledge, doing an LCC projection at lat0=0 and lat1=0 would do nothing to the actual image. Is this more what you were looking for? [Image](http://imgur.com/ADXcUS0)

Comment: @MikeJewski yes, exactly. Did you just tweak the parameters?

Comment: I would suggest reading up a bit on what LCC actually is. But in short yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust your standard parallels on LCC to get it to look conical

```
library(maps)
map("usa", projection = "mercator", wrap = TRUE)
map("usa", projection = "cylequalarea", param = 45, wrap = TRUE)
map("usa", projection = "albers", parameters = c(lat0 = 0, lat1 = 0),   wrap = TRUE)
map("usa", projection = "lambert", parameters = c(lat0 = 20, lat1 = 50), wrap = TRUE)
```